# Contact Info on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, jobs, contact

I have set up a careers.stackoverflow.com profile at [careers.stackoverflow.com/abelenky](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/abelenky), and shared it with a few potential employers.

But they rightly point out when viewing it that there is no contact info provided.
I've looked over all the profile settings, and tried to make my email and phone number visible, but haven't been able to.

If I share the URL with someone, how are they meant to contact me?

Comment: Wouldn't they contact you by replying to you using the same method you used when sharing the URL?

Comment: @Zoredache:  When I give a friend the link, its typically a fellow engineer, who forwards the link to the HR department.  At that point, the HR department doesn't have my contact info, except indirectly through the friend who referred me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is [by design](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq): prospective employers need to purchase a subscription to send messages to candidates.

One might ask why this is:

- It prevents users from getting unsolicited messages
- It gives Stack Exchange, Inc. another source of revenue
- Employers are gaining the benefit of access to high-quality new talent in exchange for a nominal fee.

If you want people to contact you outside of the Careers ecosystem, you could put that information in your public Stack Overflow profile, or on the website you link to on your Careers profile.